# How do I add the azure-devops commands to the Azure CLI in an offline on-premise server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I need to add the *azure-devops* extension to the *Azure CLI* on an on-premise Azure DevOps Server, in order to use the *az devops* commands.
The server does not have an Internet connection.

Running the following `az extension add --name azure-devops` attempts to connect to the Internet.

How do I add the azure-devops extension in an offline server?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as it only supports Azure DevOps Services, as it states on the [extensions marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.cli).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: Go to https://dev.azure.com/ms/azure-devops-cli-extension/_build, search for the Create Releases pipeline, download the published artifact and store it locally.

Then run `az extension add --source <download location>\azure-devops-cli-extension\azure_devops-0.20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Install distri:1.3.0 before

Answer (score -1):

You can download and install VSTS-Cli (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/overview?view=vsts-cli-latest) to you on-premise environment.
It is almost same as Azure-Devops.